# Fix wrong character encoding

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, character-encoding

I have a large excel file which I read with `pandas.read_excel()`. I guess it was compiled from various sources and contains some badly encoded characters.

For instance, a string `foo` which should be `für` is printed as `fãâ¼r` and has `foo.__repr__()=='fã\x83â¼r'`.
Some other string `bar` which should be `française` is printed as `franãâ§aise` with `bar.__repr__()=='franã\x83â§aise'`.
And another one `baz` which should also be `française` is printed as `franãâaise` with `baz.__repr__()=='franã\x83â\x87aise'`.

Same goes for `ñ` with a `__repr__` of `ã\x83â\x91`, and so on.

What would be the best way to sanitize this input? Or is there a way to avoid the problem altogether?

Also, is there a way to simply search for such characters in my data? A `.contains('\x')` fails as there is nothing after the unicode escape (`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape`)

Comment: Did you try to save the Excel file with another encoding? I didn't know that option existed until I looked for it. When you're in `Save As`, go to `Tools`, `Web Options`, `Encoding`, then select `Utf8`. I would try to read again with pandas and see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: @K.Cl Thanks. I just tried, and unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: You face an unprecedented [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'fã\x83â¼r franã\x83â\x87aise ã\x83â\x91' .upper() .encode('latin1') .decode() .encode('latin1') .decode() .lower()` returns `'für française ñ'`…

Comment: Interesting, thanks @JosefZ ! I checked and it worked for some of my values but not all. That's still that! I guess my data can't be cleaned with a single expression then.